# Solving a congruence -- where to start?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

For which positive integers $n$ is it true that
$$1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + (n − 1)^2 \equiv 0 \,(\text{mod } n)$$

---

I have no idea where to start. I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction. Any idea how to go about solving? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: using a well-known formula,
$$1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + (n − 1)^2=n\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}\ .$$
This is a multiple of $n$ if . . . ?